# how to ignore first 5 lines from .csv file so that I can insert data into postgresql DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql

first 5 line are informative lines and I want to ignore those lines so that rest of the lines can be inserted into postgresql DB

Answer (score 0):

When importing in postgres with COPY command from CSV you have the option "HEADER".
Using this option you can skip the first line.
But you can't skip more than one line, for this you must use a programming language that will alter the file before running postgresql's COPY command.

> HEADER Specifies that the file contains a header line with the names
>   of each column in the file. On output, the first line contains the
>   column names from the table, and on input, the first line is ignored.
>   This option is allowed only when using CSV format.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-copy.html

Comment: thanks for suggestion, now i'll proceed with node js to skip/delete those lines